# How to play a multi-player campaign?

Tags: age-of-empires-iii

The [official AoE3 website](https://www.ageofempires.com/games/aoeiii/) claims you can play "multi-player campaigns":

> **Play against your friends**
>   There are several multi-player campaigns where you can get into some heated battles with your friends.

However, the only campaign I've found in the game was the single-player one. The very "Campaign" menu option is only available after you click "Single Player" first.

There are multiplayer scenarios, but I don't think they mean that. The game itself distinguishes between "scenario" and "campaign", so does the official website, I guess.

So what are "multi-player campaigns" and how do I play them? I use "Age of Empires III: Complete Collection" [from Steam](https://store.steampowered.com/app/105450/Age_of_Empires_III_Complete_Collection/).

Answer (score 2):

There are no built in multiplayer campaigns within the game. If you want to play multiplayer campaigns, you will have to download them from 3rd party multiplayer campaign providers.

Comment: The question was not "where can I get multiplayer scenarios". The question was "what are multi-player campaigns, as mentioned at the  official site". Are you sure that when they talk about "multi-player campaigns", they mean 3rd-party multiplayer scenarios? AFAIK, "campaign" and "scenario" are to distinguished terms in AoE.

Comment: Campaigns as we all know are collections of scenarios right? So it is just a matter of downloading custom made campaigns (collections of scenarios) and playing them consecutively with your friends. I hope this makes my answer clearer.

Comment: A collection of scenarios is just a collection of scenarios. A campaign is something more — it has its own storyline and progression. A campaign *contains* scenarios, but they are not random 3rd party ones. Are you sure that when they talk about "multi-player campaigns", they mean 3rd-party multiplayer scenarios?

Comment: Even though It would be a great idea to include multiplayer campaigns within the game itself, it would create some problems like all players have to be online at the same time which could be quite uncomfortable. So yes, it would be necessary to download 3rd party scenarios from the web.

Comment: "There are several multi-player campaigns" the official site says. Are you sure that when they talk about "multi-player campaigns", they mean 3rd-party multiplayer scenarios?

Comment: Yes I'm sure. If you are not yet satisfied there might be some more info on related websites.

Comment: "*Even though It would be a great idea to include multiplayer campaigns within the game itself, it would create some problems like all players have to be online at the same time which could be quite uncomfortable.*" — are you aware of the fact there *are* RTS games that actually have multi-player campaigns? Red Alert 3, for instance.

Comment: I have never player Red Alert 3 but that is some valuable information. But there are no built in multiplayer campaigns within AoE 3. There are only 3rd party custom made multiplayer campaigns. I hope your question has been answered.

Comment: No offence, I just explain why do I think this answer is not useful in its current state. This is the actual answer: "there are no built in multiplayer campaigns within AoE 3. There are only 3rd party custom made multiplayer campaigns" (it is from your comment). This is what I did not ask: "Multiplayer scenarios are not originally included with the game. You basically have to download them from the web." (it is from your answer)

Comment: If this answer has helped you I hope you collaborate by accepting my answer. Thank you very much.

Comment: Sorry, I can't accept it unless it says "If you want to play multiplayer campaigns, you will have to download them from 3rd party multiplayer campaign providers". There is no 3rd party multiplayer campaigns, there are only 3rd party multiplayer scenarios. In all AoE series "campaign" and "scenario" are two different terms.

Comment: Why don't you just google "Download multiplayer campaigns for AoE 3" and then you will realise that there are tons of multiplayer campaigns all over the web just waiting for someone to download them. I  hope this makes my latest answer clearer.

Comment: How do they differ from multiplayer scenarios?

Comment: They are scenarios that are made by making a certain flow of story as their base and they are bunched up and uploaded online.

Comment: So they lack progression, the main part of the campaign. This scenario/campaign difference is crucial to my question. As I said, there is no 3rd party multiplayer campaigns, there are only 3rd party multiplayer scenarios. It is irrelevant if a fan called their bunch of scenarios a "campaign". They are still scenarios in terms of AoE. I repeat, the game itself distinguishes between "scenario" and "campaign", so does the official website, I suppose. That's the only reason why do I ask.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/80343/discussion-between-enkryptor-and-sofonias-ayele).